# What's the difference between an object initialised in the constructor vs properties

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have several mixins in a project I'm assigned too.
Some have their objects set in the properties like:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    config: {
      type: Object
    }
  }
}
```

While other mixins have their objects set in the constructor like:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.language = {
    name: "english",
    label: "EN"
  }
}
```

I guess both are globally accessible cause the mixins are loaded everywhere.
But what's the difference between both implementations?

edit (additional code)

These mixins get created the following way:

```
MyMixin = function (superClass) {
  return class extends superClass {

    static get properties() {
      return {
        config: {
          type: Object
        }
      }
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
    }
```

or other method:

```
MyMixin = function (superClass) {
  return class extends superClass {

    static get properties() {
      return {
      }
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.language = {
        name: "english",
        label: "EN"
      }
    }
```

and they are used by another component the following way:

```
class HomePage extends MyMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones created via Properties Object are mapped as HTML Attributes which means you can have a data binding for instance:

```
<my-component config="[[someContent]]"></my-component>
```

Variables created in constructor or connectedCallback are not mapped as HTML Attributes so you can not bind these from the outside.

```
document.querySelector('my-component').language
```

Will return

```
{
  name: "english",
  label: "EN"
}
```

but

```
document.querySelector('my-component').getAttribute('language')
```

will return undefined and

```
<my-component language="[[someContent]]"></my-component>
```

wont work

Comment: I get that, but these are mixins. You don't give attributes to them so it seems there is no difference.

Comment: Well then i did not understand the question please post some more code then.

Comment: Mh you know that mixin is just another word for parent class? so properties object from mixin will be merged with properties from component so properties object of a mixin will be mapped as attribute.